# Page property (New column - Choice type) only works for wiki pages not all site pages type

Tags: sharepoint-online, sitepages

[image]I have created a new column "Choice" in SharePoint online site pages for categorizing News.
I am able to tag new pages with the "Choice" when these pages are "Wiki Page". I want to remove that constraint from the column and able to apply this choice on "Wiki Page", "Site Page" and "Web Part Page"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply this column on "Wiki Page", "Site Page" and "Web Part Page", please ensure you have added the column in the following content types:

[image]

**Update**

Go to Site settings> Site Content Type>Site Page>Add from existing site columns to add the choice column in this content type.

[image]

Comment: I have already selected "Site Page", "Wiki Page", "Web Part Page" and "Report Page". Please see the attached image. Also, I am not facing any issues on my other Teams Site.

Comment: From your screenshot, the column not applied to Site Pages content type.Please add it and compare the result.

Comment: Could you please guide me on how to apply SIte Pages to Column. I am not able to do so

Comment: I updated my reply, please refer to it

Comment: My column is not visible in the list of "Add from existing site columns'. I am guessing that will work if the column is site column. Mine is a list column specific to site pages. Also, the site was created in late 2017 and according to this tread, the feature was rolled out in 2018 : https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/site-column-added-to-pages-library-is-not-added-to-the-site-page/m-p/214317